# graphql-codegen fails to load schema against docker based api

Tags: docker, graphql, graphql-codegen

when running the `graphql-codegen` command from visual studio code against a dockerized api service.
The command cannot connect to the live running server.

codegen.yml file

```
overwrite: true
watch: false
schema: "https://localhost:5237/graphql"
documents: "**/*.{gql,graphql}"
generates:
  src/graphql/generated/schema.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
```

Postman and a direct link to the browser can return the result from a query or view the schema definition in a typical viewer such as bananacakepop.

If I disable the graphql-codegen command and just run yarn start and use the react ui to query against the same still running docker containerized graphql server then it works.

Below is the error from graphql-codegen

```
❯ Generate to src/graphql/generated/schema.ts

✖
        Failed to load schema from https://localhost:5237/graphql:

        fetch failed to https://localhost:5237/graphql
        TypeError: fetch failed
  …
◼ Load GraphQL documents
◼ Generate
```

Does the codegen.yml file require more arguments to work with a docker container?
I have tried with and without the api service having authorization required and this did not work either.
app.UseAuthorization();

Comment: Hi, I'm having the exact same issue, have you managed to solve it ?

Comment: @Enzo one option that worked was to run the service as http rather than https and make sure that the address was updated across the project

however I have to revert that after generation as my project needs https.